# Simplifying the Derivative

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

**How do I get this simplified result from derivation outcome?**

I wish to simplify this$$-\frac {\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}+x}$$
to this
$$-\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN2Vk.png)

Comment: Please add your equations to the question itself (preferably nicely formatted). Links to external images can become invalid in the future. Don't forget to describe *what* you tried.

Comment: Try to bring the enumerator $\left(\frac x{\sqrt{\ldots}}+1\right)$ to the common denominator form.

Answer (score 2):

we have  $-\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}+x}=-\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}+x} \times \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}-x} =- \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}- \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-x}{x^2-1-x^2} = \sqrt{x^2-1}- \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$-\frac {\frac x{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+1} {\sqrt{x^2-1}+x} = 
-\frac {\left(\ \frac {x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ \right)} {\sqrt{x^2-1}+x} = 
-\frac {\left(\ \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ \right)} 1 = -\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$